# How to use a sdk (non-ros header/lib/binaries) in ros package?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, camera, ros

I am trying to use a camera sdk to write a camera stream publisher in ros.

It's not a uvc camera, so I cannot use usb_cam or other similar nodes to access the camera stream.

I've already got a sdk consisting of ASICamera.h/libASICamera.a/libASICamera.so, and I've successfully got it running.

But now I don't know how to get this running in a ros node.

Then I add the header files into the package/include directory

and #include "ASICamera.h" into the publisher node.

---

Now when I use catkin_make, it reports:

```
make[2]: *** [asi_converter_real/CMakeFiles/asi_converter_real.dir/src/asi_converter_real.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [asi_converter_real/CMakeFiles/asi_converter_real.dir/all] Error 2
```

I think the reason is that I have not add the .a and .so into the publisher node.

But I don't know how to do this

---

In the package.xml, it seems that

build_depend and run_depend tags can only access ros-inbuilt static/dynamic libraries, how could I use my own .a and .so in a ros node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your CMakeLists.txt.
Change your include dirs:

```
include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /Path/To/Include/Dirs
)
```

Set your library paths:

```
link_directories(/Path/To/Libs)
```

And add your libraries:

```
link_libraries (library_names)
```